# I can't understand a step in the proof of the associativity of matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Matrix multiplication associativity is proven by the following reasoning:

Let there be matrices $A^{m \times n}$, $B^{n \times k}$ and $C^{k \times l}$. Then

$$
\{(AB)C\}_{ij}=\sum\limits_{p=1}^k{\{AB\}_{ip}c_{pj}
\\=\sum\limits_{p=1}^k \left(\sum\limits_{q=1}^n a_{iq}b_{qp}\right)}c_{pj}
\\=\sum\limits_{q=1}^n a_{iq} \left(\sum\limits_{p=1}^k b_{qp}c_{pj}\right) 
\\= \{A(BC)\}_{ij}.
$$

I don't understand how we get the third line from the second.

Comment: the best thing to do is try it for yourself on 3 $2\times2$ matrices

Comment: There's a much more conceptual proof based on the fact that composition of linear transformations is associative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can multiply $c_{pj}$ into inner sum:
$$\sum_{p=1}^k \left(\sum_{q=1}^n a_{iq} b_{qp}\right)c_{pj}= \sum_{p=1}^k \sum_{q=1}^n a_{iq} b_{qp}c_{pj}.$$

Because the sums are finite, we can switch the order of summation:
$$\sum_{p=1}^k \sum_{q=1}^n \cdots = \sum_{q=1}^n \sum_{p=1}^k \cdots.$$

Then, since $a_{iq}$ does not depend on $p$, we can factor it out of the inner sum.
$$\sum_{p=1}^k a_{iq} b_{qp} c_{pj} = a_{iq} \sum_{p=1}^k b_{qp} c_{pj}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is, I think, a more intuitive way to prove it.

Letting A be a $m \times n$ matrix, it follows that B must have n rows for AB to exist. So letting B be a $n \times p$ matrix, (AB) will be an $m \times p$ matrix. For (AB)C to exist, C must have p rows, so let C be a $p\times r$ matrix.

C is a $p\times r$ matrix, B must have $p$ columns. So (again) letting B be an $n \times p$ matrix, BC will be an $n \times p$ matrix. For A(BC) to be allowed A must have n columns. So (again) letting A be an $m \times n$ matrix, A(BC) will be an $m \times p$ matrix.

For (AB)C and A(BC) to have the same shape, A must have the same number of columns as B has rows, and C must have the same number of rows as B has columns. When this is the case it will be true (as shown below) that $A(BC) = (AB)C$. **All we have to do is** prove that an arbitrary column of (AB)C will be equal to the same arbitrary column in A(BC) (I'll call this column the jth column of both matrices.)

$$\text{Notation: } K_i \text{ represents the ith column of the matrix } K.$$

$$B = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{B_1}}& \cdots &{B{_p}}
\end{array}} \right]$$

$$C = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
 {{c_{11}}}& \cdots &{{c_{1j}}}& \cdots &{{c_{1r}}}\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
 {\underbrace {{c_{p1}}}_{{C_1}}}& \vdots &{\underbrace {{c_{pj}}}_{{C_j}}}& \cdots &{\underbrace {{c_{pr}}}_{{C_R}}}
 \end{array}} \right]$$

$$AB = A\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
 {{B_1}}& \cdots &{B{_p}}
 \end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
 {A{B_1}}& \cdots &{AB{_p}}
 \end{array}} \right]$$

$${\left( {BC} \right)_j} = B{C_j} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
 {{B_1}}& \cdots &{B{_p}}
 \end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
 {{c_{1j}}}\\
 \vdots \\
 {{c_{pj}}}
 \end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
 {{c_{1j}}{B_1}}& \cdots &{{c_{pj}}B{_p}}
 \end{array}} \right]$$

$${\left( {\left( {AB} \right)C} \right)_j} = {\left( {AB} \right)_{{C_j}}} = AB\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
 {{c_{1j}}}\\
 \vdots \\
 {{c_{pj}}}
 \end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
 {A{B_1}}& \cdots &{AB{_p}}
 \end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
 {{c_{1j}}}\\
 \vdots \\
 {{c_{pj}}}
 \end{array}} \right] = {c_{1j}}A{B_1} +  \cdots  + {c_{pj}}A{B_p}$$

$${\left( {A\left( {BC} \right)} \right)_j} = A{\left( {BC} \right)_j} = A\left( {{c_{1j}}{B_1} +  \cdots  + {c_{pj}}{B_p}} \right) = {c_1}A{B_1} +  \cdots  + {c_{pj}}A{B_p} = {\left( {\left( {AB} \right)C} \right)_j}$$

Answer (score 0):

An $m\times n$ matrix $A=(a)_{ij}$ induces a function $f_A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$,
$$
f_A(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_{1j}x_j,\ldots,\sum_{j=1}^na_{mj}x_j\right).
$$
You can check that the composition $f_A\circ f_B$ corresponds to the matrix product $AB$, i.e. $f_{AB}=f_A\circ f_B$.

Hence associativity of matrix multiplication is implied by associativity of function composition, which holds quite generally.